# Can two apk files published on Google Play Store from different accounts be signed by the same key/keystore?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keystore

I have such problem because, I want to publish two apps from two accounts and I have strong concerns if it can be done using the same keystore and key to sign the apk files.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What is wrong with having a separate key for each account?

Comment: I have to do it because of company image and prestige reasons. It is hard to explain.

Comment: If indeed there is a way, then take all the care in preserving that keystore. Because if that is lost, you won't be able to update any of your apps that are signed by that.

Comment: It is possible but a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
You can sign the apps using the same key.

Comment: I confirm that it's possible. However, be very wary that it's not a recommended practice and will lead to trouble if you ever want to sell one of your apps since you won't be able to give the private key to the buyer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. However, it is almost certainly a bad idea. In fact it is probably the right thing for most apps to have a different signing key not only per developer account, but also per app. That way if you want to sell the rights to your app to a different company you don't have to work out what to do about the signing key for all your apps.

The very best thing in my opinion is to sign in to [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) so you have the benefit of Google protecting your signing key for you. That way if you lose your keystore or keystore password (lots of developers do this, just search StackOverflow) Google can help you out.